# How to get related list without query in JAVAScript AJAX

Tags: apex

I created a custom button which executes JAVASCRIPT,
Depending on whether a detail is present i need to display error message/redirect user.

Is there a way to get the list of related list in JAVASCRIPT without writing a query.

Say for eg;if my JS is on Lead object if i say

```
lead_record.id = "{!Lead.Id}";
```

i could get ID directly Similar is there a way to get related lists?

[i could also create a rollup summary and check for this,but want to avoid creation of fields]

Answer (score 1):

Use the name of the child relationship to check the array:

```
<script>       
    if('{!Lead.ChildRelationship__r}' == '[]'){
        alert('Related list is empty!');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In a custom button,when i say {!Account.childrelationship__r} in JS,it says such a field doesnt exist?

Answer (score 0):

OnClick query-less solution:

First, create a visualforce page. I called mine "listdata":

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="account" showChat="false" showheader="false" contentType="text/javascript">
function getContactInfo() {
return [
  <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="Contact">
  { Id: '{!Contact.Id}', Name: '{!JSENCODE(Contact.Name)}' },
  </apex:repeat>
];
}
</apex:page>
```

Next, create the button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/apex/listdata?id='&Account.Id)}
var data = getContactInfo();
alert(data);
```

Comment: Can we even get IDs here,var contactIds = '{!Account.Contacts}';  this statement gives me an error saying field doesnt exist

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of that limit, I kind of took for granted that it would work. So, you will need to do a query. Why are you so dead-set against performing a query?

Comment: nothing against query..just didnt want to perform a query,as data is so obviously there

Comment: Try my updated solution.

Comment: This looks fine.will test and close my query..thanks :)